# How do I change a UIBezierPath.currentPoint to a SKSpriteNode.position?

Tags: uibezierpath

**How do I change a UIBezierPath.currentPoint to a SKSpriteNode.position?**

Here are the appropriate code snippets:

```
func createTrainPath() {
    
    let startX = -tracksWidth/2,
        startY = tracksPosY
    
    savedTrainPosition = CGPoint(x: startX, y: startY!)
    
    trackRect = CGRect(x: savedTrainPosition.x,
                       y: savedTrainPosition.y,
                       width: tracksWidth,
                       height: tracksHeight)
    trainPath = UIBezierPath(ovalIn: trackRect)
    trainPath = trainPath.reversing()   // makes myTrain move CW
                            
}   // createTrainPath
```

Followed by:

```
func startFollowTrainPath() {
   
    let theSpeed = Double(5*thisSpeed)

    var trainAction = SKAction.follow(
                                  trainPath.cgPath,
                                  asOffset: false,
                                  orientToPath: true,
                                  speed: theSpeed)
    trainAction = SKAction.repeatForever(trainAction)
    createPivotNodeFor(myTrain)
    myTrain.run(trainAction, withKey: runTrainKey)

}   // startFollowTrainPath
```

So far, so good (I think?) ...

Within other places in my code, I call:

```
return trainPath.currentPoint
```

I need to convert `trainPath.currentPoint` to `myTrain.position` ...

When I insert the appropriate `print` statements, I see for example:

```
myTrain.position = (0.0, -295.05999755859375)
trainPath.currentPoint = (392.0, -385.0)
```

which obviously disqualifies a simple **=** , as in:

```
myTrain.position = trainPath.currentPoint
```

**Since** this **=** is not correct, what is **?**

After more investigation, my guess is that `.currentPoint` is in `SKSpriteNode` coordinates and `.position` is in `SKScene` coordinates.